# Slow Android Studio compilation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I've a client project that's bloated and it takes about 5 minutes to compile and run each time. Are there any suggestions to speed up the development time?

My suggestion is to break the project and split into modules.

I assume (please give insights) that Android Studio will create a compiled jar for each module and will reuse the compiled jar against the application as long as the module is not changed.

Please confirm if above assumption is correct.

Plus any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gradle.properties file, you can also add the following to help speed things up:

```
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
org.gradle.parallel=true

#update support to androidx
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true

# When set to true the Gradle daemon is used to run the build. For local developer builds this is our favorite property.
# The developer environment is optimized for speed and feedback so we nearly always run Gradle jobs with the daemon.
org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.configureondemand=true

kapt.incremental.apt=true
```

Comment: Thanks Kristy, can you please confirm my assumption above?

Comment: Using modules will help, definitely.  @AppDeveloper

Comment: more info: on gradle daemon, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Comment: @KristyWelsh can you give us more details on adding these specifically? when I read the documentation, they are enabled on default.